# Oracle unique constraint violation

Tags: oracle, unique-constraint

I have a table with over 30 million records. When doing insert, I need to avoid the Unique constraint violation.

When I use this NOT EXIST approach, the insert takes forever. In fact, it couldn't finish after 24 hours of running. And I can't use the `ignore_row_on_dupkey_index` hint, because this table has more than 1 PK columns.

Another option is to insert in subsets. But I want to know if there's any other way before I do sub-setting.

```
insert into tlb1 a
select * from tlb2 b
where not exists (select 'x' from tlb1 c
                  where b.pk = c.pk)
```

Comment: I need to avoid the Unique constraint violation => why? shove your data to the table, let the duplicates fail, that's what's supposed to happen

Comment: Ok, what would you do once it fails....? You would try not to insert the same record twice right? Isn't it what I did there using the NOT EXISTS?

Comment: you need to show us how you plan on doing the 30m row insert, from an existing table, a flat file, something else?

Comment: The query in my question is my plan. It's an insert to a Table from another table.

Comment: have you looked into [DML error logging](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2)?

Comment: Yes I have. This requires creating a new table for the log. It is indeed an option. But if a simple insert could do the job, I would like to avoid all these extras.

Comment: Would a merge that only processed inserts be more efficient?

Comment: Have you tried not in condition

Comment: How many rows contains tlb2?

Answer (score 1):

The important decision depends on the numbe rof row inserted, i.e. the number of the rows in the table `TBL2`

If this number is rather low (say in hundreds to thousands) you may use safely your approach, provided there is an index on the `PK` column(s) - whoch should be to enforce the unique constraint.

Please check that the used execution plan is something like the one below

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT         |          |   110 |  2860 |   113   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|   1 |  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL | TBL1     |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS ANTI      |          |   110 |  2860 |   113   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL     | TBL2     |   110 |  1430 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN     | TBL1_IXD |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("B"."PK"="C"."PK")
```

The `NESTED LOOPS ANTI` means that for each inserted row a single index lookup will be done to check if the key already exists in the target table.

This will work fine for a low number of inserted rows. For a large insert (millions rows) the optimizer will switch to a `HASH JOIN RIGHT ANTI`, i.e. all rows from both table will be joined to get th epossible duplicates.

This can take some time (but usually not 24 hours) and the approach with [DML Error Logging](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-36DB026B-4702-477A-92C4-EA2795D2B37F) which eliminates the need of the  join.

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (pk)
SELECT pk
FROM   tbl3
LOG ERRORS INTO err$_tbl1 ('dedup tbl3') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

This approach will scale well especially when the number of the duplicates is low compared with the number of inserted rows. It is comparable to a normal insert:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT         |      |   876K|    10M|   427   (1)| 00:00:06 |
|   1 |  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL | TBL1 |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL      | TBL3 |   876K|    10M|   427   (1)| 00:00:06 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```